# Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, export

Here is a part of my query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO   OUTFILE 'Target_File_Name' fields TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ''
FROM   ( 
              SELECT 'Start time', 
                     'Calling no', 
                     'Called no', 
                     'Calltype', 
                     'Cust. name', 
                     'Total Dur.', 
                     'Call stat' 
              UNION 
                    ( 
                           SELECT cdr_startdatetime, 
                                  cdr_a_number ,( 
                                  CASE cdr_b_number 
                                         WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                                         ELSE ( 
                                                CASE cdr_calltypewhen 1 THEN concat('011',cdr_b_number)
                                                       ELSE concat('1',cdr_b_number) 
                                                end) 
                                  end ), 
                                  cdr_calltype_name , 
                                  cdr_customername ,( 
                                  CASE 
                                         WHEN cdr_totalduration>0 THEN round(cdr_totalduration/60,1)
                                         ELSE 0.00 
                                  end), 
                                  cdr_callstat 
                           FROM   tlb_cdrdetails_4 FORCE INDEX(index_callstatus) 
                           WHERE  cdr_startdatetime >= cast('2012-04-01 00:00' AS    datetime) 
                           AND    cdr_startdatetime <= cast('2012-04-30 23:59:59' AS datetime) 
                           AND    cdr_callstat IN (42, 
                                                   52) 
                           AND    cdr_customerid IN (123,1000,1001) 
                           AND    cdr_carrierid  IN (114,1039,115))) tbl
```

It fetches 8 million records. It's causing a "lost connection to MySQL during query" error. Is the network speed an issue while downloading huge amount of data?

Answer (score 2):

8 million rows? - network speed will determine how long it takes to download the rows, but as to why you are losing connection, you'd have to dig deeper to see if you have a timeout setting?

Answer (score 0):

As you are facing issue in generating the CSV.

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'D:/CrossStatV3.3/Download/TempFiles//Call-Details-Report-04-01-2012_06-01-12-09-23-22.csv'........
```

Once i also faced the same issue i was generating a csv whose size was approximately supposed to 17GB.I found a work around for that

why not use `mysqldump` which is more powerful and fast.

for generating csv using `mysqldump` you can do like this

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --tab="Path where we need to create the CSV" --fields-terminated-by="\t"  --fields-enclosed-by="'" --lines-terminated-by="\n" DB_Name TableName
```

this will create the TableName.txt file and TableName.sql files at the location as you specified with --tab option where TableName.txt is your CSV you can rename it as TableName.csv.

Note : use the (--tab="PATH") path where the mysql has write permissions.

for various other options of mysqldump.

please see..

```
mysqldump --help
```

Comment: Well thnks for your reply....i have updated my actual query..can u tell me how to rewrite my query using mysqldump